# Adding logo to the navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your help. I don't really know how to add logo of my company to this code. 
 If you know what I need to do to display the logo on the navigation bar, please help me.

This is the logo:
[image: Logo]

```css
/*  import google fonts */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/* custom scroll bar */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}


/* all similar content styling codes */

section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 80px;
  margin: auto;
}

.about,
.services,
.skills,
.teams,
.contact,
footer {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.about .about-content,
.services .serv-content,
.skills .skills-content,
.contact .contact-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

section .title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

section .title::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 180px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #111;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

section .title::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: crimson;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}


/* navbar styling */

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: crimson;
}

.navbar .max-width {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .logo a span {
  color: crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky .logo a span {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 25px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover {
  color: crimson;
}

.navbar.sticky .menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* menu btn styling */

.menu-btn {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 23px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.scroll-up-btn {
  position: fixed;
  height: 45px;
  width: 42px;
  background: crimson;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.scroll-up-btn.show {
  bottom: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.scroll-up-btn:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}


/* home section styling */

.home {
  display: flex;
  background: url("images/banner.jpg") no-repeat center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.home .max-width {
  margin: auto 0 auto 30px;
}

.home .home-content .text-1 {
  font-size: 27px;
}

.home .home-content .text-2 {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 span {
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.home .home-content a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 12px 36px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.home .home-content a:hover {
  color: crimson;
  background: none;
}


/* about section styling */

.about .title::after {
  content: "who i am";
}

.about .about-content .left {
  width: 45%;
}

.about .about-content .left img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.about .about-content .right {
  width: 55%;
}

.about .about-content .right .text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.about .about-content .right .text span {
  color: crimson;
}

.about .about-content .right p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.about .about-content .right a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.about .about-content .right a:hover {
  color: crimson;
  background: none;
}


/* services section styling */

.services,
.teams {
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
}

.services .title::before,
.teams .title::before {
  background: #fff;
}

.services .title::after,
.teams .title::after {
  background: #111;
  content: "what i provide";
}

.services .serv-content .card {
  width: calc(33% - 20px);
  background: #222;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.services .serv-content .card:hover {
  background: crimson;
}

.services .serv-content .card .box {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.services .serv-content .card:hover .box {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.services .serv-content .card i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: crimson;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.services .serv-content .card:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.services .serv-content .card .text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 10px 0 7px 0;
}


/* skills section styling */

.skills .title::after {
  content: "what i know";
}

.skills .skills-content .column {
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
}

.skills .skills-content .left .text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.skills .skills-content .left p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.skills .skills-content .left a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.skills .skills-content .left a:hover {
  color: crimson;
  background: none;
}

.skills .skills-content .right .bars {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.skills .skills-content .right .info {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.skills .skills-content .right span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.skills .skills-content .right .line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

.skills .skills-content .right .line::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: crimson;
}

.skills-content .right .html::before {
  width: 90%;
}

.skills-content .right .css::before {
  width: 60%;
}

.skills-content .right .js::before {
  width: 80%;
}

.skills-content .right .php::before {
  width: 50%;
}

.skills-content .right .mysql::before {
  width: 70%;
}


/* teams section styling */

.teams .title::after {
  content: "who with me";
}

.teams .carousel .card {
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 25px 35px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.teams .carousel .card:hover {
  background: crimson;
}

.teams .carousel .card .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.teams .carousel .card:hover .box {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.teams .carousel .card .text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 10px 0 7px 0;
}

.teams .carousel .card img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.teams .carousel .card:hover img {
  border-color: #fff;
}

.owl-dots {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.owl-dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  outline: none!important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid crimson!important;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.owl-dot.active {
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}

.owl-dot.active,
.owl-dot:hover {
  background: crimson!important;
}


/* contact section styling */

.contact .title::after {
  content: "get in touch";
}

.contact .contact-content .column {
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
}

.contact .contact-content .text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contact .contact-content .left p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.contact .contact-content .left .icons {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.contact .contact-content .row {
  display: flex;
  height: 65px;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact .contact-content .row .info {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.contact .contact-content .row i {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: crimson;
}

.contact .contact-content .info .head {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.contact .contact-content .info .sub-title {
  color: #333;
}

.contact .right form .fields {
  display: flex;
}

.contact .right form .field,
.contact .right form .fields .field {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.contact .right form .textarea {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.contact .right form .name {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.contact .right form .email {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.contact .right form .field input,
.contact .right form .textarea textarea {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.contact .right form .field input:focus,
.contact .right form .textarea textarea:focus {
  border-color: #b3b3b3;
}

.contact .right form .textarea textarea {
  padding-top: 10px;
  resize: none;
}

.contact .right form .button {
  height: 47px;
  width: 170px;
}

.contact .right form .button button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.contact .right form .button button:hover {
  color: crimson;
  background: none;
}


/* footer section styling */

footer {
  background: #111;
  padding: 15px 23px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

footer span a {
  color: crimson;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer span a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* responsive media query start */

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
  .home .max-width {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1104px) {
  .about .about-content .left img {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .max-width {
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 947px) {
  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .menu-btn i.active:before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  .navbar .menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0;
    background: #111;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .navbar .menu.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .navbar .menu li {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar .menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-2 {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-3 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .home .home-content a {
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
  }
  .max-width {
    max-width: 930px;
  }
  .about .about-content .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .about .about-content .left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
  }
  .about .about-content .right {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .services .serv-content .card {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .skills .skills-content .column,
  .contact .contact-content .column {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 690px) {
  .max-width {
    padding: 0 23px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-2 {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-3 {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
  .home .home-content a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .services .serv-content .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .home .home-content .text-2 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-3 {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
  .about .about-content .right .text,
  .skills .skills-content .left .text {
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  .contact .right form .fields {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .contact .right form .name,
  .contact .right form .email {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .scroll-up-btn {
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    height: 38px;
    width: 35px;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 38px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Personal Portfolio Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.11/typed.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="scroll-up-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="logo"><a href="#">Lo<span>go</span></a></div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#home" class="menu-btn">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="menu-btn">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services" class="menu-btn">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills" class="menu-btn">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#teams" class="menu-btn">Teams</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="menu-btn">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="menu-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- home section start -->
  <section class="home" id="home">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="home-content">
        <div class="text-1">Hello, my name is</div>
        <div class="text-2">Prakash Shahi</div>
        <div class="text-3">And I'm a <span class="typing"></span></div>
        <a href="#">Hire me</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- about section start -->
  <section class="about" id="about">
    <div class="max-width">
      <h2 class="title">About me</h2>
      <div class="about-content">
        <div class="column left">
          <img src="images/profile-1.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
          <div class="text">I'm Prakash and I'm a <span class="typing-2"></span></div>
          <p></p>
          <a href="#">Download CV</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- services section start -->
  <section class="services" id="services">
    <div class="max-width">
      <h2 class="title">My services</h2>
      <div class="serv-content">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="box">
            <i class="fas fa-paint-brush"></i>
            <div class="text">Web Design</div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem quia sunt, quasi quo illo enim.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="box">
            <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>
            <div class="text">Advertising</div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem quia sunt, quasi quo illo enim.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="box">
            <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
            <div class="text">Apps Design</div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem quia sunt, quasi quo illo enim.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <div class="text">Someone name</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>

  <!-- contact section start -->
  <section class="contact" id="contact">
    <div class="max-width">
      <h2 class="title">Contact me</h2>
      <div class="contact-content">
        <div class="column left">
          <div class="text">Get in Touch</div>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos harum corporis fuga corrupti. Doloribus quis soluta nesciunt veritatis vitae nobis?</p>
          <div class="icons">
            <div class="row">
              <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="head">Name</div>
                <div class="sub-title">Prakash Shahi</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="head">Address</div>
                <div class="sub-title">Surkhet, Nepal</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="head">Email</div>
                <div class="sub-title">abc@gmail.com</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
          <div class="text">Message me</div>
          <form action="#">
            <div class="fields">
              <div class="field name">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="field email">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" required>
            </div>
            <div class="field textarea">
              <textarea cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message.." required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
              <button type="submit">Send message</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- footer section start -->
  <footer>
    <span>Created By <a href="https://www.codingnepalweb.com">CodingNepal</a> | <span class="far fa-copyright"></span> 2020 All rights reserved.</span>
  </footer>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel porta justo, in eleifend ipsum. Sed odio nisl, tristique non eros a, bibendum dictum mauris.*

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-Insert-an-Image-in-HTML-Page#:~:text=Images%20can%20be%20easily%20inserted,%3E%20tag%20inside%20%E2%80%A6 Read this and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your current logo `div` with this one:

```
 <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r87vc.png"></a></div>
```

And add these lines to your css:

```
 .logo img{
    width: 200px; // size is up to you
    height: 200px; // size is up to you
    display: block;
 }
```

*I would also recommend you to edit your .png in order to remove the big transparent border around the actual logo.*